# Mysql Foreign Key Dilemma

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

I have a column `contactId` on one table which is a foreign key, connected to the id of `contacts` table. I.e, every row in my 2nd table can be connected to a contact.

However, some records don't have to be connected to any contacts. In such cases, the contact Id would be 0. When I try to insert such a record, I get this error:

```
Error Number: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the column `contactId` that has the FK to the other table is nullable (and it can be) you should be able to just set those that don't have any contacts to `NULL`.  A foreign key basically means that if the column has a non-NULL value, then that value has to exist in the primary key of the table referenced by the foreign key constraint.  Otherwise, just set it to NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Use NULL as the `contactId` when it's irrelevant that the row reference a concact.

Foreign key columns can be nullable.